# Joining 2 tables using mulitple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SessionID   PlacesOfInterestID  PropertyID  DistrictID  SettlementID    RegionID    CountryID   PTypeID     NoOfRooms
    3              0                 0          0             1             0           0          0           2
```

Above is my interpretation of a saved search used to create a dynamic ad on a hotel booking website. I would like to be able to join this session table to the property table using any columns in the session table that have an entry in the field.

The query below returns the properties with the `settlementID` from the saved session, how could I change the query to return the properties based on whatever data is in the saved searched?

```
SELECT 
p_property.PropertyName,
p_property.PTypeID,
p_property.AvgReview,
p_property.DistrictID,
p_property.SettlementID,
p_property.NoOfFacilities 
FROM p_property 
JOIN p_session 
    ON p_property.SettlementID=p_session.SettlementID
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please remove unnecessary columns and format the querry so that your question is legible. Providing proper sample datasets also helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
SELECT 
p_property.PropertyName,
p_property.PTypeID,
p_property.AvgReview,
p_property.DistrictID,
p_property.SettlementID,
p_property.NoOfFacilities 
FROM p_property 
JOIN p_session 
    ON p_property.SettlementID=p_session.SettlementID
    OR p_property.PlacesOfInterestID = p_session.PlacesOfInterestID
    OR p_property.PropertyID = p_session.PropertyID
    OR p_property.DistrictID = p_session.DistrictID
    OR p_property.RegionID = p_session.RegionID
    OR p_property.CountryID = p_session.CountryID
    OR p_property.PTypeID = p_session.PTypeID
    OR p_property.NoOfRooms = p_session.NoOfRooms
```

(for anything that match at least one clause)